# 502 nginx can't connect to gunicorn server

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

I am so lost as to what is going wrong.

I have nginx & gunicorn running in separate docker containers. Nginx is running on port 80 forwarding to gunicorn on 8000. I get 502 errors from nginx. If I hit port 8000 I get a 200 response from my gunicorn server.

If I take down the nginx docker and start a nginx server on my laptop forwarding traffic to port 8000, everything works fine. Would could be going wrong with the dockerized nginx server setup?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '1337:80'
    depends_on:
      - django-api
  django-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application --log-level verbose --log-file=/var/log/guni --access-logfile=/var/log/gunia --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --forwarded-allow-ips "*"
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - type: volume
        source: mysql-data
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
volumes:
  mysql-data:
  static_volume:
networks:
  backend:
```

gunicorn Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE dori.settings.dev
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream hello_django {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your nginx config file. You are trying to forward request coming to nginx container to the container itself on port `8000`, just change your nginx config file to this:

```
upstream hello_django {
    server django-api:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**django-api** is the service name for you container in the network that docker-compose creates, and your other service can resolve it in the local network when trying to connect to it.